# Messages of unknown origin

Tags: cipher, visual

--storyline--

Recently, an ancient tomb of unknown origin was discovered during the deep-earth mining operations of 2035. Inside, there was a mysterious metallic box with engravings on each face, as well as a large carving on the back wall using what appears to be the same symbols.

Whatever the box is, tests have shown it to be impervious to all attempts to open it, scan it, or otherwise determine it's purpose or origin. As such, the task instead fell on the hands of those adept at deciphering unknown messages, which is where you all come in.

--task--

Using the shown images of the faces of the cube and wall carving, work out how to open the box.

Clues will be provided daily to try and nudge people in the right direction, unless that would make it too obvious.

Preferably discuss theories on what you think it could be, along with information you discover and any links to existing media you find (in general, not SE specific). I would very much like to read over how you dissect it.

I also suck at art stuff, so the images will in fact be a black-and-white pixel-art image for each face and the wall carving.

Hint 1:

> Some glyphs are used for more than one thing

Hint 2:

> Glyphs do not lose their meaning if taken away from the others

Hint 3:

> Maybe the ones who wrote the message also have dogs that lie around all day?

No hint today (#4), first 3 should allow you to decode the messages fully.

Hint 4:

> TQBFJOTLD

Hint 5:

> The name is an important entity in a video game which shares these glyphs

--images--

Wall carving:

[image]

Faces:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be 26 unique glyphs.  I have applied an english letter to each one, and I noticed that the wall carving is very sequential, with only a handful of characters actually repeating.

Comment: There are in fact 25 glyphs in total. That should suffice to tell you that it isn't simply a 1:1 conversion into english text.

Comment: Looking at the incomplete columns on the left-hand side, I think the symbols are meant to be read top-to-bottom then right-to-left.

Comment: Yes I just noticed I mapped F and Q to the same character.  Another thing to note is, there are 7 different shapes.  One being the square, and the other 6 having 4 directions each.

Comment: 2012 that may be true, but you'd been to know what you're reading first. Ryan most are just rotations of a shape, but in this question the rotation makes it a different glyph giving 25 and not 7. What made you map F and Q to the same glyph?

Comment: I was mapping them too quickly and I got careless.  The reason I brought up the 7 shapes thing is in an effort to more easily identify them and refer to them here. http://i.stack.imgur.com/adUdc.jpg

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a pretty nice way to do it, though I would do it in a 5x5 grid with the square in the corner.

Comment: @Hexi, Is that meant to be a clue, or just personal preference?

Comment: @Ryan Personally, I'm using more descriptive identifiers for the symbols... `LCGPFJO` instead of `ABCDEFG`.

Comment: It's personal preference, arranging the glyphs into a 5x5 grid shouldn't give you anything special except a nicely arranged grid.

Comment: We have to wait 20 more years until we can solve this..!

Comment: @MarkN Unless... the box contains a time-travel device?

Comment: I just noticed that the bottom right face is a bit more inset than the others, and matches the wall carving a little better. (The wall carving is smaller than the faces).

Comment: Mark I'm sure it won't take 20 years, surely after giving in excess of 7000 hints someone would have worked it out. 2012 who knows, all I can say is it's a box. Ryan, I stylised the glyph text by putting them into the smallest box of glyphs I could, in the case of the 6th box one there were simply few enough to get it onto a 7x7 box. In other words, it's insignificant.

Comment: Whether the markings are supposed to be read horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, there are cases of the same mark being adjacent to one another. This may mean they are numbers (in base 4, 6, or 24) with 2012's `O1` being 0, or adjacent markings mutate their meanings.

Comment: Hint 3: is it possible to change the word dogs with other animal names ?

Comment: Sven, the word dog is irreplaceable.

Comment: Wow, can I just say that your "it isn't simply a 1:1 conversion" hint was pretty clever in disguising the nature of the solution...  You had me thinking I was going in a totally wrong direction =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the message

> I am your guide to the location that is everywhere
> I can show you a world from a view you couldnt imagine
> I can help you transcend the limits of your environment
> Utter my name and be taken on a journey like no other
> Utter my name and see the world for what it truly is
> Utter my name and become forever changed

And his name is obviously

> Dot

Explanation for the message

> The wall panel reads "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" which was given by the most recent hint, tqbfjotld.
> Putting letters to each symbol gave the key to the cipher, where the square shaped one was a space and the symbols for the letters K/Q and U/V were shared.
> Using the cipher on the cube faces in the order given in top to bottom right to left order spells out that message.
>  And the name Dot comes from the character in the Video Game "Fez" from which these glyphs originated.

Comment: Naming the name is part of the puzzle.

Comment: Looking back on the messages after 4 days, I think I may have made it too obscure. I'll probably give a fairly strong hint as to what it is for the next due hint.

Comment: After that last hint, I'm really surprised it took this long, considering it was using Fez's glyphs exactly the same way.

Comment: Gomez is incorrect, however you're close.

Comment: If it's not Gomez, then I suppose it has to be Dot?  There doesn't seem to be much indication in the puzzle, unless I'm missing something.  Maybe because of the relevance to your name?

Comment: Honestly, I screwed up on the actual messages. Given that you would be iterating over every character in Fez, I may as well tell you it is in fact Hexahedron, the mysterious cube entity that shows you the 3rd dimension. I will however also mark your answer as correct as it contains the decoded messages.

Answer (score 6):

In case it helps somebody, I have transcribed the glyphs into a copyable format.

- Wall carving:

  ```
  L2  F4  J3  O1  F2  F1  G1
  J4  F2  O1  F3  C4  G4  P1
  P4  O1  G2  G4  L3  O1  G3
  F1  P3  L1  C1  O1  G4  F1
  J3  C4  O1  L2  F4  J3  O1
  C3  L4  C2  P2  O1  J1  G4
  J2
  ```
- Cube faces:

  ```
  G1  O1  J4  L4  P4  O1  F4  J3      F1  L2  L2  J3  C4  O1  P3
  C3  L1  O1  P2  G4  F1  O1  L2      P2  O1  P4  L4  P3  J3  O1
  C4  L4  P4  C1  J4  J3  P4  J1      L4  P4  J1  O1  F3  J3  J4
  O1  L2  F4  J3  O1  C3  G1  P3      G4  P3  J3  O1  G2  G4  C4
  G1  L2  C1  O1  G4  G2  O1  P2      J3  F1  J3  C4  O1  J4  F4
  G4  F1  C4  O1  J3  P4  F1  G1      L4  P4  J2  J3  J1
  C4  G4  P4  P3  J3  P4  L2

  G1  O1  J4  L4  P4  O1  C1  F4      F1  L2  L2  J3  C4  O1  P3  P2
  G4  P1  O1  P2  G4  F1  O1  L4      O1  P4  L4  P3  J3  O1  L4  P4
  O1  P1  G4  C4  C3  J1  O1  G2      J1  O1  C1  J3  J3  O1  L2  F4
  C4  G4  P3  O1  L4  O1  F1  G1      J3  O1  P1  G4  C4  C3  J1  O1
  J3  P1  O1  P2  G4  F1  O1  J4      G2  G4  C4  O1  P1  F4  L4  L2
  G4  F1  C3  J1  P4  L2  O1  G1      O1  G1  L2  O1  L2  C4  F1  C3
  P3  L4  J2  G1  P4  J3              P2  O1  G1  C1

  G1  O1  L4  P3  O1  P2  G4  F1      F1  L2  L2  J3  C4  O1  P3  P2
  C4  O1  J2  F1  G1  J1  J3  O1      O1  P4  L4  P3  J3  O1  L4  P4
  L2  G4  O1  L2  F4  J3  O1  C3      J1  O1  F3  J3  O1  L2  L4  F2
  G4  J4  L4  L2  G1  G4  P4  O1      J3  P4  O1  G4  P4  O1  L4  O1
  L2  F4  L4  L2  O1  G1  C1  O1      G3  G4  F1  C4  P4  J3  P2  O1
  J3  F1  J3  C4  P2  P1  F4  J3      C3  G1  F2  J3  O1  P4  G4  O1
  C4  J3                              G4  L2  F4  J3  C4
  ```

Note that I rotated +90 degrees first (so that the ragged edge fits with typical LTR writing).  Here is the glyph mapping (after rotation):

[image]

### Frequency Analysis (Glyphs)

[image]

`O` is by far the most common.

[image]

Each of the glyphs is present in each of its rotations, but one or two of the rotations are far more common.

[image]

`O` is the only glyph shape that doesn't occur twice in a row: I suspect it may be a spacer of some sort.

[image]

By far the most common (13 times) pair is `J3 O1`.  The only glyphs which occur twice in a row with the same rotation are `L2` (three times) and `J3` (once).

### Frequency Analysis (Words?)

It seems that treating `O` as a space makes some sort of sense.  If we break up each text into words, discarding the `O`s, we end up with the following distribution of word lengths:

[image]

This seems to match the distribution given [here](http://norvig.com/mayzner.html).  Looking at word frequencies, we see that several words occur more than once:

```
L2 F4 J3         5
G1               3
L4               3
P3 P2            3
L4 P4 J1         3
P2 G4 F1         3
P4 L4 P3 J3      3
F1 L2 L2 J3 C4   3
G1 C1            2
J4 L4 P4         2
P2 G4 F1 C4      2
P1 G4 C4 C3 J1   2
```

Again, this seems to match up pretty well against English.  I'm wary of proceeding too far down this route though, since OP said "it isn't simply a 1:1 conversion into English text."

(Todo: placement of repeated words.)

Comment: One thing that we both might be overlooking is the positioning within a "space" on the panels.  for instance, L3 always sits at the very top left corner of it's given space.  I wonder if this implies overlaying the letters on top of each other?  (And each letter occupies space in a 10x10 px grid.

Comment: Also, Combining L1-L4 or C1-C4 using O1 and keeping in mind the 10x10 grid creates a perfect # symbol.

Comment: @RyanB All except the `F` glyphs enter and exit the square at the 2nd and 4th row/column, this seems to support your hypothesis that they fit together somehow.  (Ever play *rivers, roads, and rails*?)

Comment: @Hex By the way, thanks for making the images pixel art: it's really easy to process them this way!  (I had *Mathematica* transcribe the pictures for me =) It's pretty automatic except for the special case of the smaller grid.)

Comment: No prob, seemed like the logical thing to do.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's probably significant that the two non-symmetric symbols (`P` and `J`) have all four rotations present, but no reflections.

Comment: It may be that all symbols are supposed to be rotations, with no reflections

Comment: If you look at the panels themselves, it's not so much word repetition as much as the panels are repeating.  The 3 panels on the top and the 3 panels on the bottom all start off the same and start diverging after a certain point.  I believe this puts a false positive in both frequency and word analysis.  I agree with the "O" theory, however hint 1 implies it has greater meaning.